# How to find out hosting provider from domain name?

Tags: hosting, dns, reverse-dns

I am looking for a reliable service that has a good database of the hosting providers vs  domain names. I guess some of the domains that are privately hosted cannot be resolved to a definite hosting provider (maybe just to ISP).

I have used webhosting.info (their power whois and advanced whois) which used to give hosting information(not sure) earlier but not anymore. I looked at domaintools.com but couldnt find anything like that in their tools.

I guess I could do a reverse IP on a domain and go to arin.net and get the org name.
But looking for a free (or paid service) that can do bulk lookups or any reverse dns tools that you recommend or use.

Comment: Is there a programming angle to this?

Comment: Seconded. Additionally, I have a hard time imagining a non-ominous-sounding context for bulk whois lookups. The mind immediately goes to the "I'm not helping a spammer" place. Could you please clarify exactly what you need to do?

Answer (score 10):

Majority of websites use DNS server provided by hosting company, but you can use any other DNS server to resolve your domain names. So looking up by IP address allocation data is the best method.

Here is a site which does it for you:

http://www.whoishostingthis.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a Linux machine, you can use jwhois on the IP address. So you'd need to resolve the hostname to IP address (which you could do using ping, if you wanted to use a shell-script) and then jwhois the IP address, which will (usually) automatically look it up in ARIN / APNIC / RIPE as appropriate. It's not 100% accurate, but it almost always works.

Alternatively, you can buy access to the [GeoIP database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location).

Comment: GeoIP is not very comprehensive when it comes to providers. But basically jwhois is a great suggestion. It can look up IPs at ARIN, RIPE, etc.. Automatically. Question is if the provider is really always listed on the IP.

Answer (score 0):

I go to [www.domaintools.com](http://www.domaintools.com) and enter the domain name in the Whois lookup.

When their Whois record shows up, look at the Name Server. It tells you who the hosting company is, and as an added bonus, also tells you the number of domains at that host.

I don't know if they have any bulk services though. I've only needed one at a time lookups.

Comment: That only tells you the domain hosting company, not the hosting company. They don't necessarily have to be the same.